# Converting between types of Graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, visualization

The above title will probably not be unfamiliar to the readers of *The Mathematica Book 5*, the former being the topic of the Section 7, Chapter 9, Part 1 of the latter, where three functions are provided: `ContourGraphics`, `DensityGraphics`, and `SurfaceGraphics`.

It was shown there that, e.g., the output of `Plot3D` can be transformed into one like the output of `ContourPlot` by `ContourGraphics`. But the problem is that I only found the above three functions deprecated when I tried to figure out how to use them. And `GraphicsComplex` is claimed to be the new version function to do the job, the documentation of which, however, seems not covering the topic.

So, how to realize the conversions among the three kinds of graphics (outputs from `ContourPlot`, `DensityPlot` and `Plot3D`) in newer verions of *Mathematica*, say after V. 11?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it is easy but it is a bad idea. You need to extract the points from the `Plot3D` and feed it into the `ListDensityPlot` and `ListContourPlot`. You need to use the `List` variants of these functions since you operate on the numerical values and not on an expression. This is the main reason, why it is a bad idea. Here is the example from the book for newer versions of Mathematica

```
plot = Plot3D[BesselJ[nu, 3 x], {nu, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 3}];
points = Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[pts_, ___] :> pts, Infinity];
dplot = ListDensityPlot[points];
cplot = ListContourPlot[points];

GraphicsRow[{plot, dplot, cplot}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The reason why it is a bad idea is that nowadays, `ContourPlot` does a much better job when it has the expressions where it really can track the contours instead of estimating them from numerical values. Just compare the smoothness of the contour lines:

```
ContourPlot[BesselJ[nu, 3 x], {nu, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For `DensityPlot` the problem is not so severe, but, still, I would suggest to let `DensityPlot` decide the sampling and give it the analytical expression.